# Reading an xls document in java, correct it with an ArrayList but no output

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, import, xls

Hey Guys I hope some of you maybe could help me.

I wrote a little Java programm which takes an xls excel data. After this the complete xls data will be moved into an ArrayList.

Then I checked with diffrent for loops if some of the single lines are double. If it is Double, the first loop should increase the position of the lines which are double to 1. At the end the sorted ArrayList will be written in a new xls document. Everything works fine but only if the xls data have less lines like, 1000 then I got no errors and fine output. But in my case I have to check over 10000 lines and then I got this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 851940, Size: 851940
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.set(Unknown Source)
at excel.excel.main(excel.java:68)
```

i used the apache poi library to work with the xls document

one line in the excel document have 13 cells the 12 cell should be checked with the rest cells of the document if it is double.

This would be a test line for example :

`Position;Surname;name;dob;telephonenmbr;postcode;city;gender;import date;nameoftheposition;result;key;doubleornot    486890;Pochor;Annette;28.08.1950;3384546194;14806;Belzig;weiblich;04.01.2016;eG_CoR_Strom_1_eveen_01-2015_TZ;Negativ beendet;AnnettePochor18503384546194;0`

This is my first time to ask a question so first of all if i did something wrong i am very sorry please correct me. I hope that its clear what my programm is doing and what the problem is. Maybe somebody can help me out

this here is the complete code of the programm :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> eineListe = new ArrayList<String>(); 

     //window which you can choose the file
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    //window which is visible. int is telling is which button got pressed
    //from user in this case it is open
    int variable = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    //checked if open got pressed

    //      if(new JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    if(variable == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            //try catch to be safe for selecting a wrong file

            try {

                    //read the file
                    HSSFWorkbook datei = new HSSFWorkbook(new
                                    FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
                    //read the first sheet
                    Sheet blatt = datei.getSheetAt(0);

                    //taking every line and every cell from this line
                    for(Row reihe : blatt) {
                            for(Cell zelle : reihe) {

                                    zelle.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                    eineListe.add(zelle.getStringCellValue().toLowerCase());


                            }
                    }

            } catch(Exception e) {}
    } //if





   for(int faktor = 11; faktor < eineListe.size(); faktor +=13) {                   // begin at the 11 cell which is the first cell which should be checked, and increasing it with 13 then go the the second line to the cell and check this one.
        String platz=eineListe.get(faktor);                                 // Placeholder to the the string to the value of cell 11
        for(int faktor2=faktor+1;faktor2 < eineListe.size(); faktor2 ++) {      // take the next line after cell 11 and check it with the rest of the document
            String platz2=eineListe.get(faktor2);                               // set the second placeholder to the value of the cell which should be checked with the first
            if(platz.equals(platz2))                                            // if two cell are same
            {                                                                   //
                eineListe.set((faktor+1), "1");                                 // set the position of the first line to 1
                eineListe.set((faktor2+1), "1");                                // set the position of the second line to 2

            }
        }
     }




    int de=0;
    HSSFWorkbook fertig = new HSSFWorkbook();           // create a new workbook
    Sheet blatt = fertig.createSheet("tabelle1");       // create and new sheet with the name table1
    for(int i=0;i < (eineListe.size()/13);i++)          // creating new cells in size of the line from the first document in this case 13

    {
        Row reihe =blatt.createRow(i);                  // create an new row
        for(int a=0;a < 13;a++) {                       // writing the value of one cell in the 13 cells


                Cell zelle= reihe.createCell(a);
                zelle.setCellValue(eineListe.get(de));

                de++;




        }
    }

    try{
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls");
        fertig.write(output);
        output.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }


}
```

}

Comment: try to add `-1` to the for loop on line 68

Comment: and for next time, it is a good practice to have all you prog in English, keine Variablename auf deutsch ;)

Comment: yes sorry for the germany names this is why i put notes to the side, but where should i excatly correct the -1 at the beginning of the for loop of 68 like a=-1 ?

Comment: no, like `for(int a=0;a < 13-1;a++) {` or `or(int a=1;a < 13;a++) {`try if it gives you the data you are waiting for

Comment: no it didnt work and the are 13 cells in one line this is why i set it too a < then 13. Starting with creating new cells in the document count by 0-12 for 13 new cells. Otherwise the would be one cell left and he will write 13 cells in 12

Comment: `for(int i=0;i < (eineListe.size()/13);i++)` should then be the failure line, try with `for(int i=0;i < ((eineListe.size()-1)/13);i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Salf here's your issue:

```
                eineListe.set((faktor+1), "1");                                 // set the position of the first line to 1
            eineListe.set((faktor2+1), "1");                                // set the position of the second line to 2
```

Your using **set** on the Arraylist out of bounds of the size in this loop:

```
for(int faktor = 11; faktor < eineListe.size(); faktor +=13) {                   // begin at the 11 cell which is the first cell which should be checked, and increasing it with 13 then go the the second line to the cell and check this one.
    String platz=eineListe.get(faktor);                                 // Placeholder to the the string to the value of cell 11
    for(int faktor2=faktor+1;faktor2 < eineListe.size(); faktor2 ++) {      // take the next line after cell 11 and check it with the rest of the document
        String platz2=eineListe.get(faktor2);                               // set the second placeholder to the value of the cell which should be checked with the first
        if(platz.equals(platz2))                                            // if two cell are same
        {                                                                   //
            eineListe.set((faktor+1), "1");                                 // set the position of the first line to 1
            eineListe.set((faktor2+1), "1");                                // set the position of the second line to 2

        }
    }
 }
```

**faktor < eineListe.size();** is checked at the beginning of the outer loop
**faktor2 < eineListe.size();** is checked at the beginning of the inner loop, but in the inner loop you are trying to set the value of an ArrayList object at "**faktor+1**"  and "**factor2+1**". If you want to do this, you need to check if there is room in the ArrayList "**faktor+1 < eineListe.size()**", and **resize** the array appropriately if not.

Hope that helps

Comment: Finally i found my misstake it was that some of the lines in the excel table where not complete they were empty this is why i got an error.